# Is a question about the reason for dislike/like appropriate?

Tags: discussion

I've got a pretty simple question: Is a question asking why people dislike/like something appropriate for discussion on Stack Exchange websites? For instance, if somebody asked, "Why do some people dislike HTML?" would that be okay for Stack Overflow, and if not would there be a different way to word it, in a way which might not sound as aggressive or angry?

Comment: Related: *[What are the Most Disliked Programming Languages?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/10/31/disliked-programming-languages/)* (official Stack Overflow blog post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its primarily opinion based - and even where we're talking technical merits, there's probably a use for seemingly useless tool in specific contexts. Its the very definition of a [textbook don't ask example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

> there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

Comes to mind.

SE's best when you're solving practical, concrete issues with at least one correct answer. Trying to understand why people dislike $answer is more or less classic polling, which works better in other contexts - but not in a Q&A site.

Answer (score 2):

No, this won't be appropriate. Questions that lead to opinion based answers are off-topic.